# MySQL: Getting&assigning number from a column of strings

Tags: mysql, data-structures

The table contains a column that contain strings. I would like to extract numbers from the string.

The code: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2af45

Eg:
1 Day = 1
2 Day anytime = 2
7 Days = 7

SameDay = 1
As for string that does not contain any number, I would like to assign a number to it.

**What I have in mind**:
[image]

What will be the best solution such that the query will not affect the loading speed greatly on MySQL?

**Additional challenge**: If the number appears randomly in the string, is there any method/algorithm that can potentially pull the number?
E.g. every 2 day, promotion in 7 days

Comment: Do the string values always start with a number, or can the number also be in the middle, eg `every 2 days`?

Comment: @Jasny-ArnoldDaniels, it always start with a number. I'm thinking maybe I should use substring(). But i'm interested to know if there is any solution that can pull the number in the middle of the string as well.

Comment: If it's starts with a number it's easy. I don't have an answer for a number in the middle at the moment.

Comment: @Jasny-ArnoldDaniels, Interested to see how you would approach this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the string starts with a number, you can simply [`CAST`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) it to an `UNSIGNED`. Any text after the number is ignored

```
CAST("2 Day anytime" AS UNSIGNED);
CAST("20 fishes" AS UNSIGNED);
```

Any string that doesn't start will a number, will become `0`. You can turn that into some other value with the combination of [`NULLIF`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_nullif) and [`IFNULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull).

```
IFNULL(NULLIF(CAST("SameDay" AS UNSIGNED), 0), 1);
```

---

You can create a new column with `ALTER TABLE` and than do an `UPDATE` query.

```
UPDATE foo (days_int)
  SELECT IFNULL(NULLIF(CAST(days_string AS UNSIGNED), 0), 1)
  FROM foo;
```

Note that the update and select is from the same table.

Comment: Hey, thanks, it works. I was wondering if I can somehow loop all the strings and produce a new column with all the new numbers?